# Unity3D How to programatically resize an image given 4 dimensions the distance from top bottom left and right of screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to resize an image using values from JSON. The JSON has values for distance (in pixels) from the top, bottom, left, and right of the screen.

I would like my image to stretch or shrink to fit the values in the JSON. I have tried:

```
myImage.preserveAspect = false;
//parent game object of image
ImageGO.getComponent<rectTransform>().sizeDelta = new vector2 (y2, x2);    
myImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (y2, x2);
```

but the image is not resizing (also width and height are not given parameters). Im using **unity 5.5** and C#.

Comment: **1**.You post your code in your question not the comment section.Edit your question and post this there. **2**.There is nothing wrong with accepting answers. I mean, go back to your other questions and accept the ones that solved your problems.

Comment: You messed the question after you last edit, please reedit the question to be again readable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to change the `anchored position` of the image inside the rectTransform to get strached, I don't have Unity on my machine now, but I believe it should help if you adapted the anchored position correctly, then the image should be resizable using `sizeDelta`.

Comment: I set the anchored position of the game object my image is attached to to stretched. I am going to post some of my code.

Comment: I need more details to be able to help you, inspector settings photo, all code dependecies, and any other important details. and to remake the questuin readable ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working most of the code I had was useless. I needed to create public vector2(s) initialize them with the values from JSON perform a few maths with them and initialize them to 
.anchoredPosition 
.sizeDelta